# How to aggregate-initialize STL container in expression with new operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, new-operator, aggregate-initialization

I'm trying to do something like:

```
using std::array;

array< array<int, 3>*, 10> arrsPtrs;

void f()
{
  arrsPtrs[0] = new array<int, 3> {1, 2, 3};         //bad!
  arrsPtrs[0] = new array<int, 3> {{1, 2, 3}};       //bad!
  arrsPtrs[0] = new array<int, 3> ( {1, 2, 3} );     //bad!
  arrsPtrs[0] = new array<int, 3> ( {{1, 2, 3}} );   //bad!
}
```

Is it possible to aggregate-initialize STL container in such expression?

PS: may be it's important - I have VS2010.

Comment: All four are fine in C++11. But a compiler from 2010 probably doesn't have complete support for a language from 2011.

Comment: May I ask why you use pointers?

Comment: VS2010 is not a C++11 compiler, it simply supports _some_ C++11 features. Even then it does not provide complete support for some of the features it includes. If you want to use C++11 get a C++11 compiler.

Comment: @leemes If You mean to use `array< array<int, 3>, 10> arrsPtrs;` instead of `array< array<int, 3>*, 10> arrsPtrs;`, then, I use ptrs because of light weight of object `arrsPtrs`, which I want to pass in a function as argument.
May be I do something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `arrayPtrs[0] = new array<int, 3> {{1,2,3}}`.

That having been said, why are you doing this? Having an array of pointers to dynamically allocated arrays is almost certainly the wrong way of going about whatever you are trying to do.

Edit: Effectively, every time you `new` something in C++, you need a corresponding `delete`. Unlike languages like Java or C# (that are garbage collected), you should rarely use a raw `new` in modern C++, as it can very easily lead to memory leaks.

Basically, instead of:

```
array<array<int, 3>*, 10> arrsPtrs;
```

You instead would want to use:

```
array<array<int, 3>, 10> arrsPtrs;
```

If you want to pass this to a function, you can simply pass it by (const) reference:

```
void some_function(const array<array<int, 3>, 10>& arr)
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: I'm only a beginner in programming. And almost certainly I'm doing something wrong. Can You write, what is a common good practice of implementation something like it in similar situations? And can You write two more words about why is it wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3241228 you should definitely download a memory debugger by the way. I would personally recommend drmemory. That way you can check to make sure you aren't getting any memory leaks by forgetting `delete`s